# Is it possible to have private functions (let definitions) in F# modules?

Tags: .net, f#

I'd like to make `applyAndTruncate` hidden from the outside world (that is, from anything outside the `Scoring` module), as I really only use it as backbone for `bestKPercent` and `worstKPercent`. Is it possible to hide it? If not, what is the F#ish way of accomplishing what I want to do?

```
module Scoring
    let applyAndTruncate f percentage (scoredPopulation:ScoredPopulation) : ScoredPopulation =
      if (percentage < 0.0 || percentage > 1.0) then
        failwith "percentage must be a number between 0.0 and 1.0"

      let k = (int)(percentage * (double)(Array.length scoredPopulation))

      scoredPopulation
      |> f
      |> Seq.truncate k
      |> Seq.toArray

    let bestKPercent = applyAndTruncate sortByScoreDesc
    let worstKPercent = applyAndTruncate sortByScoreAsc
```

Comment: I hardly know anything about F#, but perhaps [the F# spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597594) is helpful. It seems you can add accessibility annotations to let bindings.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes. `let private myfunc =` will do it.

Comment: And for recursive functions you should put the `rec` before `private`

Answer (score 13):

You can also use [signature files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx) to specify the public interface of a corresponding implementation file. Then the idea is that you don't worry about accessibility until the implementation has solidified. I've honestly not ever used them, but they are used in the F# compiler source code extensively (probably just because I'm comfortable with the implementation site style used in so many other languages, whereas folks with original ML experience will be at ease with signature files; also, [you do get some extra features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526902/signature-files-and-access-modifers-in-f/1526983#1526983) with signature files, though nothing super compelling).

So if your `Scoring` module were implemented in a file named `Scoring.fs`, you'd have a corresponding signature file named `Scoring.fsi` that would look something like:

```
namespace NS //replace with you actual namespace; I think you must use explicit namespaces
module Scoring =
    //replace int[] with the actual ScoredPopulation type; I don't think you can use aliases
    val bestKPercent : (float -> int[] -> int[])
    val worstKPercent : (float -> int[] -> int[])
```

Comment: I might use signature files if I could right-click a *.fs file in Visual Studio and "Generate Signature File". As it is, if I want one I either have to look up the syntax to write it by hand, or I have to look up the command-line parameters to have the F# compiler generate one for me, and then add the file to the project. So far, I haven't felt the need acutely enough to bother.